# Laravel validation for this number +852 1111 2222?

Tags: html, laravel

Suppose we have number +852 1111 2222 in format .What is the Laravel validation for this number(regular expression) with + symbol and allow space between number?

```
'phone_number'  => 'required|regex:/(^[0-9 ]+$)+/',
```

Comment: Yes a regular expression might be a good option (but so many other solutions could work as well). We can't tell you what to do with your code we can only help you fix issues with the code you actually write to solve your problems.

Comment: how about `regex:/^\+[0-9 ]+$/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression will be good example for you as you the format of phone number won't change you cant take this regex patter as example

```
'phone_number'  => 'required|regex:/^\+\d{3}\s\d{4}\s\d{4}$/',
```

In case the phone number prefix doesn't change you can include it directly in the pattern like this

```
'phone_number'  => 'required|regex:/^\+852\s\d{4}\s\d{4}$/',
```

Here is the link to [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KI47iP/1)